# Python object to file path? Error in Syntax

Tags: python

When I trying to add the following file path,

```
data = ‘c:/vehicles/etc’
```

I am wondering why I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier ??
```

In addition to this, I have also tried:

```
data = 'C:\vehicles'
```

which produces a similar error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Is there something new in python I'm missing to set up file paths?

Answer (score 1):

```
data = ‘c:/vehicles/etc’
```

Here you have fancy quotes that you probably copy/pasted from somewhere, like a Word document. Delete those and type in regular quotes.

---

```
data = 'C:\vehicles'
```

Here you need to escape the `\` character so Python knows it's a literal `\` and not an escape sequence.

```
data = 'C:\\vehicles'
```

Alternatively, prefix the sting literal with an `r` to tell Python it's a raw string.

```
data = r'C:\vehicles'
```

Comment: mmm I tried regular quotes/ also tried \ / different ways .. still have the error

Comment: train_data = "C:\vehicles"
test_data = "C:\vehicles"

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

?

Comment: @3eternus `\v` isn't a recognized escape sequence. Add another \.

Comment: Ok i fixed it seems to be when I copied and pasted it into the notebook.. 

This has been confused for hours? 

Is there extra spacing appearing which we can't see

Comment: @3eternus That's a possibility. Some things can be mistranslated when copy/pasting from one document format to another. (Sometimes I'll paste text into Notepad first to avoid this.)